# Can I map multiple database tables to a unique Entity using JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to add multi-language to the **description** and **title** fields of one of my Entities but without success. My Entity is like below and my database is MySQL:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class ProjectEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="team_size")
    private Integer teamSize;
    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;
    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;
    @OneToMany
    private List<DetailsEntity> details;
}
```

I alreaady tried to add a projectDetails entity that contains the description and title, but as I need multilanguage, the Project will now have a list of ProjectDetails in my backend, what I don't need.
Here is what the projectDetails could looks like:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "project_details")
public class ProjectDetails implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;
    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;
    @Column(name="language")
    private String language;
    @Column(name="project_id")
    private Integer projectId;
}
```

I would like to be able to do something with the JPA repository requests, like this:

```
@Repository
public interface ProjectEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<ProjectEntity, Integer> {

    @Query("select p from ProjectEntity p left outer join ProjectDetails d on p.id=d.project_id and d.language=:language")
    List<ProjectEntity> findAllForLanguage(String language);
}
```

Any idea on how to change part of this to return the Project entity with values of only 1 ProjectDetails?

Thank you

Comment: No.  The easiest thing to do is have a single abstract class that holds the fields, extends the class for each table and override the @Id field.

Comment: good idea thank you